# How to show options in mode vertical in a ice:selectManyCheckbox?

Tags: java

How to show options in mode vertical in a ice:selectManyCheckbox?

I need to show a list of options the menu in mode vertical. At this time I show horizontal.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ice:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use selectManyCheckbox and dataTable is...

=== Page.xhtml ===

```
<ice:selectManyCheckbox id="idSelectManyCheckbox" layout="spread"
   value="#{MyBean.selectedsValuesCheckbox}" >
   <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.selectItemsCheck}"/>
</ice:selectManyCheckbox>

<ice:dataTable varStatus="rowVar"
   value="#{MyBean.listOfMyObjects}" var="anyNameVar">

   <ice:column>
      <ice:checkbox for="idSelectManyCheckbox" index="#{rowVar.index}" />
   </ice:column>
   <ice:column>
      <ice:outputText value="#{anyNameVar.property1}" />
   </ice:column>

   <!-- ... more columns .. -->
</ice:dataTable>
```

=== MyBean.java ===

```
private List<MyObject> listOfMyObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>(3);
private List<String> selectedsValuesCheckbox = new ArrayList<String>(2);
private SelectItem[] selectItemsCheck = new SelectItem[3];

private handleSelectItemsCheck(){
   int idx = 0;
   selectedsValuesCheckbox.add("1");
   selectedsValuesCheckbox.add("3");
   for (MyObject myObject : listOfMyObjects) {
      selectItemsCheck[idx++] = 
    new SelectItem(myObject.property1, myObject.property2); // value and label
   }
}
```

// Gets and sets

================================================================

```
*you must use layout="spread" in that situation.
*in the table the checkboxs 1 and 3 will be selected. because "selectedsValuesCheckbox"
```